# Error in plot.window(...) : invalid 'ylim' value

Tags: r

New to R and need help! I am getting Error in plot.window(...) : invalid 'ylim' value after each plot statement in the following code. Can someone assist on this? Since I don't have ylim in the statement, am I supposed to add it?  I couldnt find anything that tells me it is required.  I am using RStudio.  The dataset is a CSV file.

```
library(tidyverse)
names(file1)
library(zoo)
x=data.frame(file1)
dt= seq(as.Date("2017-08-22"),as.Date("2018-08-22"),by="days")
GAS=zoo(x,dt)
GAS
plot(GAS$G1.close, xlab='date(08-22-2017 to 08-22-2018)', ylab = 'G1.close')
plot(GAS$A1.close, xlab='date(08-22-2017 to 08-22-2018)', ylab = 'A1.close')
plot(GAS$g2.return, xlab='date(08-22-2017 to 08-22-2018)', ylab = 'g2.return')
plot(GAS$a2.return, xlab='date(08-22-2017 to 08-22-2018)', ylab = 'a2.return')
```

[image: first 10 lines of dataset]

Comment: Try `plot(as.numeric(GAS$G1.close), xlab='date(08-22-2017 to 08-22-2018)', ylab = 'G1.close')`

Answer (score 0):

One issue is that when you call `seq` to make the dates, it creates a sequence of dates for every day from the start date to the end date, but in your data there are some days that are skipped. Try the following to read the data from the csv file and see if it works.

```
library(readr)
library(lubridate)
library(zoo)
GAS=read_csv("insertfilenamehere.csv", col_names=TRUE,
             col_types="cdddd")
GAS$Date=mdy(GAS$Date)
GAS=zoo(GAS[-1], GAS$Date)
plot(GAS$G1.Close, xlab="date", ylab="G1.close")
```

[image]